# Unable to typeset vectors using physics package

Tags: math-mode, typography, vector, physics

I'm trying to typeset the equation for the dot product like this (using the physics package).

```
$$ \va{A} \dot \va{B} = abs{A}abs{B}\cos{\theta}$$
```

However, LaTeX keeps throwing this:

```
./AP Physics Notes.tex:29: Missing } inserted. [$$ \va{A} \dot \va]
./AP Physics Notes.tex:29: Missing } inserted. [$$ \va{A} \dot \va]
./AP Physics Notes.tex:29: Extra }, or forgotten $. [$$ \va{A} \dot \va]
./AP Physics Notes.tex:29: Extra }, or forgotten $. [$$ \va{A} \dot \va]
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong...any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't use `$$....$$` please. Try `\[ .... \]` around it

Comment: Use `\cdot` not `\dot`!

Answer (score 3):

`\dot` is a command requiring a parameter, to set a dot above some character, to indicate the time derivative. The multiplication dot can be obtained using `\cdot`!

Another error were the missing `\` (but without complaining) just before `abs`.

Please don't use the outdated `$$....$$` syntax -- use `\[....\]` instead.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\LARGE 
\[ \va{A} \cdot \va{B}  = \abs{A}\cdot \abs{B}\cdot \cos{\theta}\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't use the same symbol with two distinct meanings. The problem of the two bars too near to each other can be solved by `\,` between them

Comment: @egreg: Well, I personally prefer a `\circ` as indicator for the dot product. On the other hand: `\cdot` operates in the vector space for the vectors and on the rhs on the field of real numbers ... physicists are sometimes a little bit lazy ;-)

Comment: Also `$$...$$` is deprecated, not outdated. Just to be a picky mathematician. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: I already wrote that in a comment and in the post ;-) And the *norm* bars (:-P) are not too narrow for my impression, but I always write a dot between multiplied quantities, as students sometimes get confused otherwise ;-)